# Prolog: why do I end up with list with anonymous variables

Tags: prolog

I would just like to write a predicate, which takes two lists: `L1` and `L2`, and I want the third element to return the first `N` elements of `L2`, where `N` is the length of `L1`. Suppose I could assume that `L2` is longer than `L1`, and I do not want to use the built-in `length`, so I tried to do like this:

```
getFirstPart([],_,_).
getFirstPart([H1|T1],[H2|T2],[H2|T3]) :- getFirstPart(T1,T2,T3).
```

And when I try, it gives me

```
?- getFirstPart([1,1,1],[1,2,3,4,5,6],L).
L = [1, 2, 3|_5081628].
```

Could anyone tell me what is wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Let's have a look at the derivation tree. We start with the goal

```
getFirstPart([1,1,1],[1,2,3,4,5,6],L).
```

Applying the recursive rule, we obtain a new goal

```
getFirstPart([1,1],[2,3,4,5,6],L2).
```

with `L = [1 | L2]`. The same happens during the next recursion step:

```
getFirstPart([1],[3,4,5,6],L3).
```

with `L2 = [2 | L2]`. Once more and we obtain

```
getFirstPart([],[4,5,6],L4).
```

with `L3 = [3 | L4]`. Then the base case kicks in. When we put the substiutions together we obtain `L = [1,2,3 | L4]` with no constraints on `L4`. The name `_5081628` is just the internal name of `L4` in your Prolog interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

The free variable is due to the base-case:

```
getFirstPart([],_,_).
```

Here you write basically:

> If the first parameter is the empty list, I do not care about the second parameter, nor the third, these can be anything.

Since the recursive case each time "eats" an element, eventually we will invoke the base case, and so we never properly "close" the list.

The solution is to specify how the last parameter should look like: an empty list, so:

```
getFirstPart([],_,[]).
getFirstPart([H1|T1],[H2|T2],[H2|T3]) :-
    getFirstPart(T1,T2,T3).
```

So here we more or less say:

> If the first parameter is the empty list, then we do not care about the second parameter, but the third parameter is the empty list as well.

Note that in the recursive case, there is an variable that only occurs once: `H1`, we can replace this with an underscore `_`:

```
getFirstPart([],_,[]).
getFirstPart([_|T1],[H2|T2],[H2|T3]) :-
    getFirstPart(T1,T2,T3).
```

Comment: Super! Thank you so much!